# Twig path function - passing an array of parameters

Tags: arrays, loops, parameters, path, twig

How to pass **an array of parameters** to the **path** function of **Twig** (the Sensiolabs template engine)?

An example:

```
<a href="{{ path(item.getRoute(), {'foo':'bar', 'foo_2':'bar'} ) }}">xxx</>
```

My array of parameters:

```
item.getParameters()
```

In the array there are appropriate keys names and corresponding values.
How to iterate `item.getParameters()` inside the path function?

Answer (score 3):

the solution is surprisingly simple:

```
<a href="{{ path(item.getRoute(), item.getParameters() ) }}">xxx</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig has the very same behaviour as PHP.

Consider the following PHP function :

```
function test($array)
{
  // something with $array
}
```

You can call it this way :

```
test(array('foo' => 'bar', 'foo_2' => 'bar'));
```

Or this way :

```
test($item->getParameters());
```

Assuimg that your `getParameters()`'s method returns `array('foo' => 'bar', 'foo_2' => 'bar')`.

So, as @user1183754 mentionned, you can use :

```
<a href="{{ path(item.getRoute(), item.getParameters() ) }}">xxx</a>
```